# Retrieve list of last inserted ids

Tags: mysql

```
 insert into table1 (select * from table2);
```

where table 2 has 10 records. I want to retrieve list of 10 ids (which is autoincreamnet)  from `table1` that has been inserted.

Comment: @Xatenev In the absence of an ORDER BY clause, LIMIT is pretty much meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

If they're auto-incremented, then you want to select the 10 highest numbers. Select the id and sort by the id descending and then limit to 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use desc and limit

```
   INSERT INTO table1 (SELECT * FROM table2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10)
```